# JIT ramp up time for .NET web services

Tags: .net, web-services, jit

How do I overcome JIT compilation ramp-up time for infrequently used web service methods in my .NET enterprise solution? Some of my infrequently used business processes rely upon 5-6 web internal web service calls. Each "JIT" can add 2-3 seconds per call adding roughly 10-15 seconds to a process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) the assemblies beforehand - or (if they're harmless to call for no other reason) just have a task to make the calls periodically.